# How to clear an autocomplete textbox component when dropdown component onChange selection occurs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, textbox, components

I have a React app with 2 separate components in a parent component: a dropdown component ( `SearchDropdown`) and an autocomplete textbox component (`Autocomplete`).

```
 <div className="sidebar" style={{
      borderLeft: "1px solid gray"
 }}>
     <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "grey" }}>Filter By:</h2>
     <hr style={{ color: "grey", marginBottom: "20px" }} />
     <form onSubmit={(e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         const { state } = autoCompleteRef.current;
         const keys = searchDropdownRef.current.state.userInput;
         callSearchAPI(state.userInput, keys);
     }}>
         <SearchDropdown ref={searchDropdownRef}
             onSearchDropdownChange={listHandler}
         />
         <hr style={{ color: "grey", marginBottom: "20px" }} />
         <label style={{ color: "grey" }}>Enter Value</label> <br />
         <Autocomplete ref={autoCompleteRef}
             suggestions={autoData}
             style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }} />
         <button className="btn btn-primary" > Search</button>
     </form>
 </div >
```

I have a modest goal here. Whenever the dropdown selection changes, I want to clear any text in the Autocomplete textbox. I have tried using a DOM selector in my `listHandler()` function called in the `SearchDropdown` component's `onSearchDropdownChange event. This method works in the browser console:

```
 function listHandler(searchKey) {
    document.getElementById("autocomplete").value = "";
    setKey(searchKey);
    const auto_key = { searchKey };
    let temp = "";
    if (auto_key.searchKey == 'name') {
        temp = { namesData };
        return setAutoData(temp.namesData);
    } else if (auto_key.searchKey == 'title') {
        temp = { titleData };
        return setAutoData(temp.titleData);
    } else if (auto_key.searchKey == 'email') {
        temp = { emailData };
        return setAutoData(temp.emailData);
    } else if (auto_key.searchKey == 'phone') {
        temp = { phoneData };
        return setAutoData(temp.phoneData);
    } else if (auto_key.searchKey == 'county') {
        temp = { countyData };
        return setAutoData(temp.countyData);
    } else if (auto_key.searchKey == 'affiliation') {
        temp = { affiliationData };
        return setAutoData(temp.affiliationData);
    } else {
        return setAutoData([]);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work in the code but does work in the browser? How can I clear this textbox when the dropdown selection changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, I first had to add a handleReset function in my Autocomplete component:

```
class Autocomplete extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        filteredSuggestions: [],
        showSuggestions: false,
        userInput: ""
    };
}

handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
        userInput: ""
    });
};
```

In my parent component, I had already added `useRef()` to reference my `Autocomplete` and `SearchDropdown` components.

```
export const Table = () => {
//For Sidebar Search
    const autoCompleteRef = useRef();
    const searchDropdownRef = useRef();
```

I then called my original `listHandler` function when the `SearchDropdown` component selection changed and added my reference to the `handleReset` function using the `AutocompleteRef` like this:

```
 function listHandler(searchKey) {
    document.querySelector('input[id=autocomplete]').value = "";
    autoCompleteRef.current.handleReset();
    ...
 }
```

It works now.